# How can I use PHP to Create Non-Predictable Cookie Session IDs

Tags: php, session, magento, cookies, pci-compliance

I have a site that needs to pass PCI compliance.

The site using Magento 1.5.1 (Magento is a PHP based system) and the PCI complience failure is Predictable Cookie Session ID's.

I'm under the assumption this means they want the cookie in Magento named "frontend" changed to a random UUID. I would assume this is possible to do without modding or extending the core, but I cant find a setting to do this.

Thoughts?

Heres the vulnerability description:

The remote web application is using predictable cookie-based session 
IDs. Ideally, session IDs are randomly generated numbers that cannot 
be guessed by attackers. If the session ID is predictable, an attacker 
could hijack an active victim's

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help, but this is as secure as I know how to get on a session setup.  I'd love to be corrected by someone more knowledgable than I, since it would directly affect all my e-commerce projects.

there is a `current_domain()` function referenced in the code below that comes from my [opensource framework](http://code.google.com/p/tgsf/source/browse/trunk/tgsf_core/libraries/tgsfUrlDetection.php) (link is to file containing the function).  If you don't need dynamic domain replacement you can just hard code your domain there.

```
<?
ini_set( 'session.use_trans_sid',       false                   );
ini_set( 'url_rewriter.tags',           ''                      );
ini_set( 'session.use_cookies',         true                    );
ini_set( 'session.use_only_cookies',    true                    );
ini_set( 'session.name',                sha1( current_domain()  ) ); // current domain is a function implemented in tgsf
ini_set( 'session.cookie_lifetime',     0                       ); // until browser is closed.  I implement this server side

ini_set( 'session.hash_function',           1 ); // sha-1
ini_set( 'session.hash_bits_per_character', 6 );

// only if host is not localhost 
ini_set( 'session.cookie_domain', 'www.example.com' );

// use for localhost
//ini_set( 'session.cookie_domain', null );

ini_set( 'session.cookie_path', '/' ); // limit as much as you can for security
ini_set( 'session.cache_limiter',           'nocache' ); //prevents back button displaying a page after session is dead
ini_set( 'session.cookie_httponly',         true ); // helps prevent xss by preventing javascript access to the session cookie (on SOME browsers, not all)
```